# "BUG: scheduling while atomic" in a simple custom module

Tags: linux, module, atomic, schedule

I wrote a simple module which emulates a force feedback input device so that I can test the underlying FFB implementation. However, the module sometimes crashes the kernel with the "scheduling while atomic" message. According to the backtrace the crash is triggered by ff_dummy_open() and I can reproduce it easily by destroying and recreating the dummy device a couple of times in a row through sysfs. What am I doing wrong?

Source of the module:

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/sysfs.h>
#include <linux/input/ff-logitech.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

struct ff_dummy_device {
    struct input_dev *dev;
    int slot;
};

static struct kobject *ff_dummy_kobj;
static struct ff_dummy_device **ff_dummy_devices;
static int max_device_count;
static unsigned char device_count = 0;
static struct mutex mtx;

static const char *ff_dummy_name = "DumFFBD";

static const signed short ff_dummy_effects[] = {
    FF_CONSTANT,
    FF_PERIODIC,
    FF_TRIANGLE,
    FF_SAW_UP,
    FF_SAW_DOWN,
    FF_SINE,
    FF_SQUARE,
    FF_SPRING,
    FF_DAMPER,
    FF_INERTIA,
    FF_FRICTION,
    FF_RAMP,
    -1
};

static int ff_dummy_control(struct input_dev *dev, void *data, const struct lgff_effect_command *command)
{
    struct ff_dummy_device *ddev = data;

    switch (command->cmd) {
    case LGFF_START_COMBINED:
        pr_debug("Force X: %d, Force Y: %d, (idx %d)\n", command->u.simple_force.x, command->u.simple_force.y, ddev->slot);
        break;
    case LGFF_STOP_COMBINED:
        pr_debug("Stopping COMBINED effect (idx %d).\n", ddev->slot);
        break;
    case LGFF_START_UNCOMB:
        pr_debug("Starting UNCOMBINABLE effect.\n");
        pr_debug("LC(x): %d RC(x): %d, LS(x): %d, RS(x): %d\n",
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[0].left_coeff,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[0].right_coeff,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[0].left_saturation,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[0].right_saturation);
        pr_debug("LC(y): %d RC(y): %d, LS(y): %d, RS(y): %d\n",
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[1].left_coeff,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[1].right_coeff,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[1].left_saturation,
            command->u.uncomb.effect->u.condition[1].right_saturation);
        switch (command->u.uncomb.effect->type) {
        case FF_DAMPER:
            pr_debug("Starting DAMPER id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_FRICTION:
            pr_debug("Starting FRICTION id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_INERTIA:
            pr_debug("Starting INERTIA id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_SPRING:
            pr_debug("Starting SPRING id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case LGFF_STOP_UNCOMB:
        pr_debug("Stopping UNCOMBINABLE effect.\n");
        switch (command->u.uncomb.effect->type) {
        case FF_DAMPER:
            pr_debug("Stopping DAMPER id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_FRICTION:
            pr_debug("Stopping FRICTION id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_INERTIA:
            pr_debug("Stopping INERTIA id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        case FF_SPRING:
            pr_debug("Stopping SPRING id %d\n", command->u.uncomb.id);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void ff_dummy_close(int idx)
{
    if (idx < 0 || idx > max_device_count) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "Invalid device index.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!ff_dummy_devices[idx])
        return;

    mutex_lock(&mtx);
    input_unregister_device(ff_dummy_devices[idx]->dev);
    kfree(ff_dummy_devices[idx]);
    ff_dummy_devices[idx] = NULL;
    device_count--;
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Dummy force feedback %u device removed.\n", idx);
}

static int ff_dummy_open(int idx)
{
    struct ff_dummy_device *newdummy;
    struct input_dev *newdev;
    int i, ret;

    if (idx < 0 || idx >= max_device_count) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "Invalid device index.\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    newdummy = kzalloc(sizeof(struct ff_dummy_device *), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!newdummy) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to allocate memory for dummy device slot.\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    mutex_lock(&mtx);
    if (ff_dummy_devices[idx]) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "Selected slot %u already occupied.\n", idx);
        mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        kfree(newdummy);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    ff_dummy_devices[idx] = newdummy;

    newdev = input_allocate_device();
    if (!newdev) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to allocate memory for input device.\n");
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto open_err;
    }

    newdev->id.bustype = BUS_VIRTUAL;
    newdev->id.vendor = 0xffff;
    newdev->id.product = 0x0001;
    newdev->id.version = 0x0001;
    newdev->name = ff_dummy_name;
    newdev->uniq = kasprintf(GFP_KERNEL, "%s_%u", ff_dummy_name, idx);
    set_bit(EV_FF, newdev->evbit);

    /* Make the device look like force feedback device */
    for (i = 0; ff_dummy_effects[i] >= 0; i++)
        set_bit(ff_dummy_effects[i], newdev->ffbit);

    ret = input_register_device(newdev);
    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to register dummy device.\n");
        input_free_device(newdev);
        goto open_err;
    }

    ret = input_ff_create_logitech(newdev, (void *)ff_dummy_devices[idx], ff_dummy_control);
    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to register dummy device with ff-logitech\n");
        input_unregister_device(newdev);
        goto open_err;
    }

    ff_dummy_devices[idx]->dev = newdev;
    ff_dummy_devices[idx]->slot = idx;
    device_count++;
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Dummy force feedback %u device created.\n", idx);
    return 0;

open_err:
    kfree(ff_dummy_devices[idx]);
    ff_dummy_devices[idx] = NULL;
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    return ret;
}

static ssize_t ff_dummy_add_device_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    int ret;
    mutex_lock(&mtx);
    ret = scnprintf(buf, PAGE_SIZE, "%u\n", device_count);
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    return ret;
}

static ssize_t ff_dummy_add_device_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf,
                                         size_t count)
{       
    int ret;
    int idx = 0;

    sscanf(buf, "%d", &idx);

    ret = ff_dummy_open(idx);

    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Dummy device creation failed with errno %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    return count;
}

static ssize_t ff_dummy_del_device_show(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    int i;
    int ret = 0;

    mutex_lock(&mtx);
    for (i = 0; i < max_device_count; i++) {
        if (ff_dummy_devices[i])
            ret += scnprintf(buf + ret, PAGE_SIZE, "[%u] ", i);
        else
            ret += scnprintf(buf + ret, PAGE_SIZE, "%u ", i);
    }
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    ret += scnprintf(buf + ret, PAGE_SIZE, "\n");
    return ret;
}

static ssize_t ff_dummy_del_device_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf,
                                         size_t count)
{
    int idx = 0;

    sscanf(buf, "%d", &idx);        
    ff_dummy_close(idx);

    return count;
}

static struct kobj_attribute add_device_attr = 
        __ATTR(add_device, 0644, ff_dummy_add_device_show, ff_dummy_add_device_store);
static struct kobj_attribute del_device_attr =
        __ATTR(del_device, 0644, ff_dummy_del_device_show, ff_dummy_del_device_store);

static struct attribute *attrs[] = {
    &add_device_attr.attr,
    &del_device_attr.attr,
    NULL
};

static struct attribute_group attrs_grp = {
    .attrs = attrs
};

static void __exit ff_dummy_exit(void)
{
    int i;

    sysfs_remove_group(ff_dummy_kobj, &attrs_grp);

    for (i = 0; i < max_device_count; i++)
        if (ff_dummy_devices[i])
            ff_dummy_close(i);

    kfree(ff_dummy_devices);
    kobject_put(ff_dummy_kobj);

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Dummy force feedback module removed.\n");
}

static int __init ff_dummy_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    if (max_device_count < 1)
        max_device_count = 2;

    ff_dummy_kobj = kobject_create_and_add("ff_dummy_device_obj", kernel_kobj);
    if (!ff_dummy_kobj)
        return -ENOMEM;

    ff_dummy_devices = kcalloc(max_device_count, sizeof(struct ff_dummy_device *), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!ff_dummy_devices) {
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto err_alloc;
    }

    mutex_init(&mtx);

    ret = sysfs_create_group(ff_dummy_kobj, &attrs_grp);
    if (ret)
        goto err_sysfs;

    ret = ff_dummy_open(0);
    if (ret)
        goto err_open;
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Dummy force feedback module loaded.\n");
    return 0;

err_open:
    sysfs_remove_group(ff_dummy_kobj, &attrs_grp);
err_sysfs:
    kfree(ff_dummy_devices);
err_alloc:
    kobject_put(ff_dummy_kobj);
    return ret;
}

module_param_named(max_device_count, max_device_count, int, S_IRUGO);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(max_device_count, "Maximum number of dummy devices that can be created simultaneously.");
module_exit(ff_dummy_exit);
module_init(ff_dummy_init);
```

EDIT:
The scheduling problem might have been a false lead. The only thing I am certain about is that the crash happens deep inside input_register_device(). "in_atomic()" and "in_interrupt()" return 0.

EDIT:
Solved. The actual bug was caused by a double free error in the underlying ff-logitech module and incorrect allocation of "struct ff_dummy_device *" instead of "struct ff_dummy_device".

Comment: Your're trying to call something that can block from a context in which it is not allowed

Comment: I figured as much, but what could it be? ff_dummy_open() uses mutex to serialize device creation and AFAIK it's safe to sleep with mutex held. It happens even when I remove the locking from ff_dummy_open() altogether.

Comment: It's probably not because of something you did that it's unsafe to sleep, it's the context the kernel is calling into your code from, I'm not a kernel developer, but this lwn article looks like a good place for you to start http://lwn.net/Articles/274695/

Comment: kzalloc with GFP_KERNEL can sleep, and it should be GFP_ATOMIC